# Throw exception if method arguments are invalid

Tags: java

I am kind of new to java so pardon this rather simple question, I guess. This method will count how many digits are there on a **POSITIVE** integer only. So it needs to throw an error to the caller. How do I do so when the input is negative, I throw an error and exit the method without returning anything?

```
public static int countDigits(int n)
    {
        if (n<0)
        {
            System.out.println("Error! Input should be positive");
            return -1;
        }
        int result = 0; 
        while ((n/10) != 0)
        {
            result++;
            n/=10;
        }
        return result + 1;
    }
```

Comment: `throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input should be positive")`. You can Google what it does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not throwing an error here; you're displaying an error message and returning a sentinel value of `-1`.

If you want to throw an error, you have to use the `throw` keyword, followed by an appropriate `Exception`.

```
public static int countDigits(int n) {
    if (n < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Input should be positive");
    }
    int result = 0;
    while ((n / 10) != 0) {
        result++;
        n /= 10;
    }
    return result + 1;
}
```

The [Java Trails](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html) on throwing exceptions will provide you with invaluable insights into what different kinds of exceptions there are.  Above, `IllegalArgumentException` is considered a runtime exception, so something that is calling this method won't be forced to catch its exception.

Answer (score 0):

You need to throw an exception.

```
if (n < 0) {

    throw new Exception("n must be a positive integer");
}
```

You can make life easier for callers of your method by using a more specific exception type. In this case, `IllegalArgumentException` would be appropriate.

```
if (n < 0) {

    throw new IllegalArgumentException("n must be a positive integer");
}
```

Different types of error can be handled separately in a try-catch.

I would take a look at [Guava's preconditions](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) to do this in a cleaner fashion.

Comment: Please don't use the generic `Exception` class. Java comes with many useful standard exception classes, for example the `IllegalArgumentException`. I'd suggest using it in this case.

Answer (score -2):

It depends. If the caller doesn't handle an eventual failure, then I'd throw an exception. But it is much simpler to return a value like -1 and then check the result after the call. Exceptions are slow.

Comment: Using Exceptions is cleaner more meaningful though. I would argue that that is more important.

Comment: This isn't an answer because the questioner asked how to throw an exception.

Comment: Well in most cases it is. But since other answers have already discussed exceptions I thought it would be useful to show an alternative

Comment: If the caller is aware of this and doesn't want to end up with an exception, they can check the value before they pass it in. Exceptions should be rare, so the speed is irrelevant... "Exceptions are slow" is almost *never* a good argument for avoiding them.

Comment: This is a bad answer. Without exception you will pollute your code with unnecessary if else. As Jon Skeet also said, you're not expected to call an function with an invalid input.